# How to measure extremely high temperatures?

Tags: measurement, heat, pid-controller, thermocouple, thermometer

I'm interested in building or buying an electric (arc or induction) furnace for smelting & heat-treating metals.

Most designs I've seen utilize PID controllers and thermocouples.

How are extreme temperatures accurately reached and measured without damaging (i.e. melting) the precision measuring instruments (e.g. thermocouples, etc.)?

Comment: Thermopiles are a thing. Don't know how they measured things like 2000-3000C before they existed though.

Comment: @DKNguyen Probably by observing the colour.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Well you could tell when some temperature of consequence was reached but I mean like actually measure and assign a number.

Comment: Old enough metalworking texts do use dull red, cherry red, orange, yellow etc in heat treatment "recipes". - and of course the much lower tempering temperatures were indicated by colour, but this time from the thickness of oxide layers, e.g. in blue steel.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Everything I know about bue steel I learned from Zoolander.

Comment: Usually non-contact methods such as *pyrometry* are used. Other methods I've seen are specialized known-composition samples that are observed as they melt -- used often in kilns, for example. Several are placed and you can tell the temperature by which of them slag over more than others in a fixed time. But you've not mentioned your accuracy specification. This is likely the most serious issue for us to know, before suggesting anything. I've worked on devices capable of measuring 3000 Kelvin with accuracies better than 50 ppm and NIST can do still better. Special cases and not cheap, though.

Comment: Just accurate within a few degrees celcius will be fine.

Comment: @DKNguyen how does a thermopile withstand such high temperatures?

Comment: @voices It doesn't. It just doesn't need to be at the same temperature it is measuring because contactless. A thermopile is what an IR thermometer uses in case you did not know. They measure the temperature DIFFERENCE between the target and their own temperature. They are basically thermocouples.

Comment: @DKNguyen how so? isn't it just an array of thermocouples?

Comment: @voices Technically, yes. But thermocouples can be made of many materials and thermopiles are made of something quite unlike your contact thermocouples and optimized differently.

Comment: @DKNguyen how is it no contact

Comment: Please read up on thermopiles.

Comment: @DKNguyen i believe i have

Comment: Then what is it you don't get?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "extreme" but base metal thermocouples (eg. K, N) work okay up to >1000°C depending on atmosphere, precious metal thermocouples (eg. R, S, B) to perhaps 1600°C and tungsten/rhenium thermocouples to well over 2000°C and briefly to perhaps 3000°C.

There are also optical pyrometers. In the olden days one would match the appearance of a filament against the light from a furnace, which works up to quite high temperatures (perhaps 3000°C).

Comment: By extreme I mean anything >1000°C but particularly >2000°C. Enough to soften or liquify glass or steel or iron and so forth. Thanks for your answer.